# How to have different lua versions on the same linux system

Tags: linux, lua

I'm trying compile VLC on fedora 23. I have Lua 5.3.3. ./configure is telling me I need Lua 5.1 or Lua 5.2. Can I have 5.1 and 5.3.3 on the same system without breaking stuff? If so, how?

Comment: You may wish to look into [luaver](https://github.com/DhavalKapil/luaver), which might at least help you get through the compilation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can. According to [fedoraproject.org](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/lua/contents/) Lua is packaged to be installed separately for different versions.

**Generic sollution**

In general, during Lua environment run-time You can manage usage of different Lua versions by setting `LUA_PATH` and `LUA_CPATH` environment variables.

Specifically, for VLC You could set Lua installation related environment variables [1]:

```
LUA_CFLAGS  C compiler flags for LUA, overriding pkg-config

LUA_LIBS    linker flags for LUA, overriding pkg-config

LUAC        LUA byte compiler
```

[1] https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_configure_help/

**Automatic version management**

For independent from distribution Lua version and Lua modules management we have couple of initiaves:

- [LuaRocks](https://luarocks.org/) --- one of the older and bigger Lua modules management system.
- [LuaDist](http://luadist.org/) --- another quite old management system, looks like... create with PiP in mind.
- Other projects, for example [luaver](https://github.com/DhavalKapil/luaver) (mentioned by [Brandon Anzaldi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1905944/brandon-anzaldi)) which is quite new and still gaining momentum (no proper releases as of 2016-06-14).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [luaver](https://github.com/DhavalKapil/luaver) for installing, managing and switching between different versions of lua. It is a very easy to use program.

To install `luaver` run:

> curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dhavalkapil/luaver/master/install.sh -o install.sh && . ./install.sh

Then you can install and use multiple versions of lua as follows:

> luaver install 5.3.1             # Installs lua version 5.3.1
>
> luaver install 5.3.0             # Installs lua version 5.3.0
>
> luaver use 5.3.1                 # Switches to lua version 5.3.1

See https://dhavalkapil.com/luaver/ for more details.